# String array assignment in Ruby function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variable-assignment

I am new to Ruby and pretty new to programming in general. Have no idea why string[n]=temp[string.length-(n+1)] would change temp as a string array. Isn't the assignment ONLY changes string array? I have been on this problem for 4 hours, any help would be very appreciated =) thank you!

```
 def reverse(string)
  temp = string
  n=0
  while (string.length - n) > 0 
    string[n]=temp[string.length-(n+1)]
    n+=1
  end
  return string
end

puts reverse("abc")
```

Comment: Temp and string are the same object.

Comment: @FrederickCheung, is that a reference instead of a copy?

Comment: If I add `puts "string.object_id == #{string.object_id}, temp.object_id == #{temp.object_id}"` after `temp = string`, when I execute `reverse("abc")`, the following is printed:  `string.object_id == 70267640537340, temp.object_id == 70267640537340`. Does that tell you something? You need `temp = string.dup` (though I haven't looked at the rest of your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp` and `string` are the same object because of:

```
temp = string
```

So, any changes to `string` will be reflected in `temp`. You can duplicate the string variable instead to avoid this problem:

```
temp = string.dup
```

Comment: worked perfectly thanks. Do you guys know if there is any literature that educate me on "=" assignment operator on Ruby. It seems to be very different from what I used to with variables. Thank you again!

Comment: @MarkThomas and what is that may I ask?